# Is there a tablet-centric desktop available for Ubuntu?

Tags: desktop-environments, ubuntu-touch, tablet

I have a Lenovo x61 tablet PC running Ubuntu 10.04. I've got [Karol Krizka's](http://www.krizka.net/2008/02/13/thinkpad-x61-tablet-automatic-screen-rotation-under-linux/) auto-rotate daemon working, along with a variety of other applications like [cellwriter](http://risujin.org/cellwriter/), though for some reason even when it's working properly, it needed a [fix](http://wjw.blogspot.com/2009/08/cellwriter-fix.html) for me. There's a host of other applications I use such as

- xournal, for general notetaking
- mypaint, for drawing
- easystroke, for gesture recognition

probably others that I forget at the moment...

But I was wondering if there are any good tablet-oriented desktop environments for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really isn't any out there currently - but what you may want to install is the new [UNE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Netbook_Edition) ([Ubuntu Netbox Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Netbook_Edition)) which provides the new launcher application on the destkop itself. Should make using a tablet a lot more effective.

To get this to work you'll need to add this [ppa]: `ppa:netbook-remix-team/ppa` to your system and install the relavant packages. It took me quite some time to hunt down this repository for some reason. I believe you'll then want to execute `sudo apt-get install unity ubuntu-netbook-unity-default-settings` and any other [packages](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-dx-team/+archive/une/+packages) listed.

Comment: It is also worth to watch the talk held by Mark Shuttleworth at Debconf 10: http://penta.debconf.org/dc10_schedule/events/531.en.html

Comment: You can also go to application > ubuntu software center and search for ubuntu-netbook and install it that way (I couldn't get the ppa to work)

Comment: Thank you for the update Wayne - it appears that repository is used for the "preview" release, since 10.04 the official release is packaged as `ubuntu-netbook`

Answer (score 1):

[gnome-shell](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell) looks like it's going to be a serious contender for tablet interfaces. Other than that, I'd try out the various netbook-orientated environments like Ubuntu Netbook Edition.

To test out gnome-shell I recommend not using the repo version which is a very long way behind the current development version and instead use a PPA like so:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

To use it just fire off:

```
gnome-shell --replace
```

To turn it off:

```
metacity --replace
```

To remove it:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge -p testing ricotz
```

Answer (score 0):

For a touch interface, you could use [LXDE](http://lxde.org/) + [lxlauncher](http://lxde.org/lxlauncher) or the GNOME + netbook-launcher (the launcher from the current (10.04) netbook edition).

To add to your applications list you could use [fennec](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/fennec/1.0a1/releasenotes/), a touch oriented browser.
Also look [here](http://www.alwaysinnovating.com/wiki/index.php/Applications_list) for a list of applications bundled with  a touch oriented OS (most, but not all, will be available for Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

The new ubuntu touch ui is well supported on the tablet . But it is not completed yet